# Selecting from string from 2nd array based on 1st array results

Tags: c#

I'm looking to make selections from a second array, based on the results in my first array. The first array stores integers of the position of certain column headers reside in a csv.

```
var path = @"C:\Temp\file.csv";
using (TextFieldParser csvImport = new TextFieldParser(path))
{
    csvImport.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
    csvImport.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
    csvImport.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

    string[] header = csvImport.ReadFields();
    foreach (string colheader in header)
    {
        index = index + 1; //this bit will return where my column headers are in the header line
        if (colheader == "FirstColumn")
        {
            key = (index - 1); //stores int of my result
        }
        else if (colheader == "SecondColumn")
        {
            secondkey = (index - 1); //stores int of my result
        }
    }

    csvImport.ReadLine();   //Behaves as carriage line return, this moves to position 2 before loop

    while (!csvImport.EndOfData)
    {
        //Read each field, build Sql Statement
        string[] fields = csvImport.ReadFields();
        string MyKey = fields[1];   //Currently this is static pos 1 I want it to be the result of key 
        string MySecondKey = fields[74]; //Currently this is static pos 74 I want it to be the result of SecondKey 
    }
}
```

is there a simple way of assigning a variable into the [] to ad hoc pick out my array based on other variables at my disposal?

I've edited the question slightly as what I am looking to achieve is picking the field from a csv line based on the indexes from the first arra

```
            //Read each field, build Sql Statement
        string[] fields = csvImport.ReadFields();
        string MyKey = fields[1];   //Currently this is static pos 1 I want it to be the result of key 
        string MySecondKey = fields[74]; //Currently this is static pos 74 I want it to be the result of SecondKey
```

Comment: I didn't get what MyKey, and MySecondKey are.

Answer (score 0):

Give the items in your second array an index (`i` here), then get all items that their index is in first array:

```
secondArray.Select((x,i) => new {x, i})
         .Where(z => firstArray.Contains(z.i))
         .Select(z => z.x);
```

and here is a [live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XYihCF)

(of course the type of second array is not important and I have used `string[]` just for simplicity, and it can be an array of a class, ... )

Comment: As much as it is so neat, i still can't get myself like linq, way too much syntactic sugar.

Comment: I also added a demo that you can check

Comment: I've added a bit more to my initial question as I think it could have been phrased clearer.
My second array is a static variable within an array, more insight in the question above
also, thank you Ashkan for your feedback thus far